# ruby on rails 3 - StateMachine Not Moving to Next State with Testing with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capybara, factory-bot, state-machine

I am writing integration tests using factory girl capybara. My site is using state_machine gem. 
I am logging the transitions and the events are being called however the state is not sticking.
I mocked up the same data my factory girl model is filling in and it works in developement env; however in test env it is not sticking. I am thinking I am missing something simple.

I thought I would check to see if others have had this issue and have a solution.
I am using
rails', '3.2.8'
ruby 1.9.3
and all gems are up to date.